# Joint pdf random variables

Tags: statistics

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables that have a joint p.d.f. given by $p(x,y)=2⋅\frac{(x+2y)}{3}$ when $0≤x,y≤1$ 
and $p(x,y)=0$ for all other $x,y$. Find the probability that $X<(1/3)+Y$.

I'm solving a double integral with the integral in terms of $x$ from $1/3+y$ and the $y$ integral from $0$ to $1$. However, I keep getting an answer that is greater than one which is absurd for a probability. Any help please?

Comment: Unless you show your workings (instead of *describing* them), how can we help?

Comment: I explained my work above. I set up a double integral of the functionP(x,y) with outside integral y going from 0 to 1 and inside integral x going from 0 to (1/3 +y).

Comment: The upper bound of the integral in x should not be 1/3+y for every y but min(1,1/3+y). Which result do you get with this modification?

Comment: what do u mean by min(1,1/3+y)?

Comment: The minimum: 1/3+y when y<2/3 and 1 when y>2/3.

Comment: i am still confused....

Comment: By what exactly?

Comment: by what the bounds should be for the integral, are u hinting that should two double integrals

Comment: @user143875 Note that the definition of $p(x,y)$ requires $x \le 1$. This is where the $\min$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be erroneously computing, with $f(x,y)=\frac23(x+2y)$:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{1/3+y}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
What you should be computing:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{\min\{1,1/3+y\}}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
that is,
$$
\int_0^{2/3}\int_0^{1/3+y}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+
\int_{2/3}^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$

Comment: ok this kind makes sense but why are the bound 0 to 1 for the second double integral

Comment: Because I typed too quickly. Good catch!

Comment: thanks so much for your help, it makes sense now